# Outlook 2010 on PC Banner is stretched showing space on html newsletter? Anyone?

Tags: html, outlook

I also have the html code attached below if anyone wants to see this tragedy:) I am very new to coding and this is my first foray into what hopefully will be many more to come. I appreciate any and all help somebody can offer

[If you see banner you can see the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9Qv5.png)

`enter code here`"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
`enter code here`

```
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">

            body { margin: 0; padding: 0; border:0; }

            @media only screen and (max-width: 660px)  {
                table.container {width: 480px !important; }
                td.logo img { display: none; }
                td.logo { background: #fff url(images/logo-med-2.png) no-repeat 17px 13px; height: 45px; }
                td.banner img {display: none; }
                td.banner {width: 480px; height: 150px; background: url(images/atten-it_medium.jpg) no-repeat 0px 0px; }
                td.content { padding: 17px !important; }
                td.content table.button {width: auto; }
                td.content table.button td a { font-size: 14px !important; }
                td.callout { padding: 20px 30px 20px 18px !important; }
                }

            @media only screen and (max-width: 510px)  {
                table.container {width: 380px !important; }
                td.container td {border: none !important; }
                td.logo { background: #fff url( images/logo_small_2.png) no-repeat 10px 13px; height: 32px; }
                td.banner img {display: none; }
                td.banner {width: 250px; height: 116px; background: url(images/banner-small-it2.jpg) no-repeat 0px 0px;}
                td.content { font-size: 12px;  padding: 15px !important; }
                td.footer { padding: 20px 30px !important; }
                td.callout { padding: 20px 30px 20px 16px !important; }
                td.callout table { width: 100% !important; margin-bottom: 20px; }
                td.callout table td { padding: 0px 0px 10px 50px !important; background-size: 50px
                50px !important; min-height: 60px; }
                td.callout table a { display: inline; }
                td.callout table br.spacer { display: inline; }
                }

        </style>

<style type="text/css">

</style>
</head> 
    <body bgcolor="#cecfcb">

    <div style="font-size: 1px; color: #cecfcb; display: none;">
      welcome to where you will see some preview text in the email that is not even 
      placed in the newsletter so to customize perhaps a preview of what to expect in
      the newsletter if we like.
    </div>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#cecfcb">
        <tr>
            <td>

            <table class="container" width="640" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
            <td valign="top" class="logo" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 10px 20px 10px 18px; border-left: 0px; border-right: 0px; border-top: 0px">
                    <a href="http://www.sjo.org/" target="_blank"><img src="images/logo_large_2.png" alt="st joe" width="585" height="45" border="0"></a>
                </td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="banner">
                <a href="http://www.sjo.org/" target="_blank"><img src="images/banner_large_it.jpg" alt="so green" width="640" height="180"></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff" class="content" 
                style="padding: 30px 30px 30px 18px; border-right: 0px; 
                border-left: 0px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height:22px; color: #000000; background:
                #ffffff no-repeat 0px 0px;">
                <h1 style="margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px; font-weight; normal; font-size: 25px; color: #004250;" align="Left">Hello, CHELSEY!</h1>

                <table width="160" align="right" class="button" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 15px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #488cdf; padding: 10px 15px; border-radius: 10px;">
                        <a href="http://www.sjo.org/" img alt="" target="_blank" style="color: #fff; font-size: 18px; letter-spacing: 1px; text-decoration: none; text-
                            shadow: 0px 2px 2px #3a5606; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Learn More</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consec tetur adip isicing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
                Ut enim ad minim veniam quis nostrud exercita tion ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure 
                dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum eu fugiat nulla.


            <br>

                </td>
            </tr>

        <tr>


                <td valign="top" bgcolor="#ec7a08" class="callout" style="background-color: #526388; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;
                padding: 20px; border-right: 0px; border-bottom: 0px; border-left: 0px">

                <font color="#ffffff">&copy; St. Joseph Health. PLEASE DO NOT REPLY TO THIS MESSAGE:
                <br><br>    
                 Your <a href="http://www.sjo.org/" target="_blank" style="color:#cecfcb;">privacy</a> is important to us. Please use this link to <a href="http://www.sjo.org/" target="_blank" style="color:#cecfcb;"
                >unsubscribe</a>.
                <br><br>
                Questions, Comments, and Concerns? Ping engagement@<a href="mailto:engagement@stjoe.org" target="_top" style="color: #ec7a08; "> engagement@stjoe.org</a></font>
                </td>

        </tr>
    </table>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: You should post your code, it makes it a lot easier to help

Comment: yessir I have attached it above (I re-edited the initial string with the code) and thank you as well for taking the time to look at this